# What source control do you use for Report Builder 2.0?

Tags: sql-server, version-control, reporting-services

I want to use the new report builder 2.0, rather than the old VS2005 integrated report builder for the new features and ease of use, but source control integration is a must.

I don't see any ability to use TFS natively, and I have installed the [TFS MSSCCI Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FAEB7636-644E-451A-90D4-7947217DA0E7&displaylang=en), all with no love.

Does anyone know how to get them to play well, or am I looking at this from the wrong angle.

How do you version control your SQL reports?

Comment: I agree ... I thought about writing a utility to download all of the files daily and put them into git/TFS etc....  it seem rather lacking that they give you a robust web interface to make all of these queries but no way to integrate them into VS or TFS???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Report Builder you can just open RDL files from the filesystem but yes, it doesnt integrate with TFS directly or any source control package. You need to VS I'm affraid. So you can checkout, open in report builder.. save then check back in.

Comment: Not the answer I like, but it does seem to be the answer.

Comment: You know if is the same with Report Builder 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

RB2 doesnt use a traditional file system interface but instead uses the reportserver web service to communicate with files on the report server. Because of this disconnect you wont find any simple answers - but one suggestion. If you are running in sharepoint integrated mode you could possibly get some level of change tracking.